# Eigenvectors computed with numpy's eigh and svd do not match

Tags: python, numpy, svd, eigenvector

Consider singular value decomposition M=USV*. Then the eigenvalue decomposition of M* M gives M* M= V (S* S) V*=VS* U* USV*. I wish to verify this equality with numpy by showing that the eigenvectors returned by `eigh` function are the same as those returned by `svd` function:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
# create mean centered data
A=np.random.randn(50,20)
M= A-np.array(A.mean(0),ndmin=2)

# svd
U1,S1,V1=np.linalg.svd(M) 
S1=np.square(S1)
V1=V1.T  

# eig
S2,V2=np.linalg.eigh(np.dot(M.T,M))
indx=np.argsort(S2)[::-1]
S2=S2[indx]
V2=V2[:,indx]

# both Vs are in orthonormal form
assert np.all(np.isclose(np.linalg.norm(V1,axis=1), np.ones(V1.shape[0])))
assert np.all(np.isclose(np.linalg.norm(V1,axis=0), np.ones(V1.shape[1])))
assert np.all(np.isclose(np.linalg.norm(V2,axis=1), np.ones(V2.shape[0])))
assert np.all(np.isclose(np.linalg.norm(V2,axis=0), np.ones(V2.shape[1])))

assert np.all(np.isclose(S1,S2))
assert np.all(np.isclose(V1,V2))
```

The last assertion fails. Why?

Comment: You can add a positive number to all the diagonal elements, i.e. make M2=M+a*I, where a is large enough to make M2 positive semidefnite. Then SVD and eigh should agree better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just play with small numbers to debug your problem.

Start with `A=np.random.randn(3,2)` instead of your much larger matrix with size `(50,20)`

In my random case, I find that

```
v1 = array([[-0.33872745,  0.94088454],
   [-0.94088454, -0.33872745]])
```

and for `v2`:

```
v2 = array([[ 0.33872745, -0.94088454],
   [ 0.94088454,  0.33872745]])
```

they only differ for a sign, and obviously, even if normalized to have unit module, the vector can differ for a sign.

Now if you try the trick

```
assert np.all(np.isclose(V1,-1*V2))
```

for your original big matrix, it fails... again, this is OK. What happens is that some vectors have been multiplied by `-1`, some others haven't.

A correct way to check for equality between the vectors is:

```
assert allclose(abs((V1*V2).sum(0)),1.)
```

and indeed, to get a feeling of how this works you can print this quantity:

```
(V1*V2).sum(0)
```

that indeed is either `+1` or `-1` depending on the vector:

```
array([ 1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.])
```

EDIT: This will happen in most cases, especially if starting from a random matrix. Notice however that this test will likely fail if one or more eigenvalues has an eigenspace of dimension larger than `1`, as pointed out by @Sven Marnach in his comment below:

> There might be other differences than just vectors multiplied by -1.
>   If any of the eigenvalues has a multi-dimensional eigenspace, you
>   might get an arbitrary orthonormal basis of that eigenspace, and to
>   such bases might be rotated against each other by an arbitraty
>   unitarian matrix

Comment: @matus OK, I'm lost :) But I trust in your judgment, and so I'll remove my comments not to confuse future readers. Cheers!

Comment: There might be other differences than just vectors multiplied by -1.  If any of the eigenvalues has a multi-dimensional eigenspace, you might get an arbitrary orthonormal basis of that eigenspace, and to such bases might be rotated against each other by an arbitraty unitarian matrix.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, this is a very valid point. I will edit the post to point out this caveat